# Python: Executing alarm in console while listening to key stroke

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to implement an alarm which displays remaining time in console with some other features like stop and resume etc.

The desired output in console is:

`Time Remaining: 00:10:02 # This timer keeps decreasing
Input Alarm Action: # User inputs actions here`

I have two questions:

- Should I use two threads to do this? One is the alarm thread and the other is the keyborad listener thread which includes an alarm instance? I heard thread is useless in Python. Is there any better idea?
- What module should I choose to listen to the screen/keyboard/console? I prefer to listen to keyboard itself so I don't have to switch to console when I'm working on other apps.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For which OS?
You can use Cruses/Urwid to realize this. A extra Thread isn't needed, but so difficult implement.
select.select is a good opinion to wait for inputs.
Here is a good example: https://github.com/popoklopsi/RaspberryPi-LedStrip/blob/master/fading.py
This example is only work under Linux in bash.